# How to assign a value from the last row of a preceding group to the next group?

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to put the digits from the last row of the previous letter group in the new column "last_digit_prev_group". The expected, correct value, as a result formula, was entered by me manually in the column "col_ok". I stopped trying shift (), but the effect was far from what I expected. Maybe there is some other way?
Forgive me the inconsistency of my post, I'm not an IT specialist and I don't know English. Thanks in advance for your support.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../a.csv',names=['group_letter', 'digit', 'col_ok'] ,
                                                                                index_col=0,)


df['last_digit_prev_group'] = df.groupby('group_letter')['digit'].shift(1)

print(df)

group_letter digit col_ok  last_digit_prev_group
                                     
A                 1      n                    NaN

A                 3      n                    1.0

A                 2      n                    3.0

A                 5      n                    2.0

A                 1      n                    5.0

B                 1      1                    NaN

B                 2      1                    1.0

B                 1      1                    2.0

B                 1      1                    1.0

B                 3      1                    1.0

C                 5      3                    NaN

C                 6      3                    5.0

C                 1      3                    6.0

C                 2      3                    1.0

C                 3      3                    2.0

D                 4      3                    NaN

D                 3      3                    4.0

D                 2      3                    3.0

D                 5      3                    2.0

D                 7      3                    5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for last valeus of `digit`, then [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and last `ffill`:

```
df['last_digit_prev_group'] = (df['digit'].mask(df.duplicated('group_letter', keep='last'))
                                          .shift()
                                          .ffill())

print (df)

   group_letter  digit col_ok  last_digit_prev_group
0             A      1      n                    NaN
1             A      3      n                    NaN
2             A      2      n                    NaN
3             A      5      n                    NaN
4             A      1      n                    NaN
5             B      1      1                    1.0
6             B      2      1                    1.0
7             B      1      1                    1.0
8             B      1      1                    1.0
9             B      3      1                    1.0
10            C      5      3                    3.0
11            C      6      3                    3.0
12            C      1      3                    3.0
13            C      2      3                    3.0
14            C      3      3                    3.0
15            D      4      3                    3.0
16            D      3      3                    3.0
17            D      2      3                    3.0
18            D      5      3                    3.0
19            D      7      3                    3.0
```

If possible some last value is `NaN`:

```
df['last_digit_prev_group'] = (df['digit'].mask(df.duplicated('group_letter', keep='last'))
                                          .shift()
                                          .groupby(df['group_letter']).ffill()

print (df)
   group_letter  digit col_ok  last_digit_prev_group
0             A    1.0      n                    NaN
1             A    3.0      n                    NaN
2             A    2.0      n                    NaN
3             A    5.0      n                    NaN
4             A    1.0      n                    NaN
5             B    1.0      1                    1.0
6             B    2.0      1                    1.0
7             B    1.0      1                    1.0
8             B    1.0      1                    1.0
9             B    3.0      1                    1.0
10            C    5.0      3                    3.0
11            C    6.0      3                    3.0
12            C    1.0      3                    3.0
13            C    2.0      3                    3.0
14            C    NaN      3                    3.0
15            D    4.0      3                    NaN
16            D    3.0      3                    NaN
17            D    2.0      3                    NaN
18            D    5.0      3                    NaN
19            D    7.0      3                    NaN
```

Comment: How to enter in the new column "last_digit_MAX_prev_group" a digit with the maximum value from the previous group of letters. I don't know how to modify the code df ['last_digit_prev_group'] = (df ['digit']. Mask (df.duplicated ('group_letter', keep = 'last')). Shift (). Ffill ())
  to get the expected value? Which part of the code should be modified and how? I tried to change in the mask (df.duplicated ('group_letter', keep = 'last')) area keep = 'last'
but none of the available options ("keep = first", False) produce the expected result. You can help?

Comment: I added one line of code and I have the expected effect: df = df.assign(max1 = df.groupby('group_letter')['digit'].transform('max'))  and df ['last_digit_prev_group'] = (df ['digit']. Mask (df.duplicated ('group_letter', keep = 'last')). Shift (). Ffill ()) Well, unless there is something simple?